# vb6 ocx project - can run EXE directly, not in debugger

Tags: vb6, activex, ocx

I have a VB6 ActiveX control project (creating an `.OCX`), which has several User Controls. The controls are being loaded by an EXE (also VB6). When I run the EXE directly, it runs OK, but when I try to run it in the debugger (I need to step through the code), it cant't load the user controls (.ctl), gives me "Class not registered. Looking for object with CLSID:..." message

I have the Binary Compatibility set (kept all the old GUIDs), and I see the classes in the registry, everything looks OK - just doesn't run in debugger.

Any help please?

Comment: Are both Projects being opened as a Project Group?

Comment: no, the project is for the OCX, and the EXE is in Debuging->Start Program

Comment: Ok, then it sounds like compatibility has been broken.  Does the error dialog show the full CLSID?  If so, does it match what you see in the registry?  And are you running the VB6 IDE elevated?

Comment: the error dialog does show the full CLSID;

Comment: But does it match the registry value, and are you running VB6 elevated to help avoid registry virtualization?

Comment: the error dialog does show the full CLSID;
the CLSID does match what I see in the registry;
it's Windows XP; I'm an Admin and Debugger user (domain), but not the same user that installed the VB6/Visual Studio (did I get the 'elevated' part right?). There is a potential complication with permissions - it's a corporate environment - but the same user (me) can run everything alright as long as it's not in debugger

Comment: "Elevated" basically means to run as admin so you're covered.  I'm out of ideas.

Comment: :-( me too; thanks for your time nonetheless, I appreciate your help

Comment: You said "it cant't load the user controls (.ctl)". Have you added the `.ctl` files directly to the second project or are you referencing the compiled `.ocx` file?

Comment: the .ctl files are parts of the ActiveX (.OCX) project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been working with VB6 for over a decade now. The problem is that the VBP project reference is out of sync with the latest build of your OCX user control. Simply open the project as a group or the EXE project on it's own and click Project->Components.

You will now see one of two things. Either the reference will be invalid or you have a valid reference chosen. Either way, uncheck the reference and click okay (do not re-select it during this operation.. trust me). Now, close that dialog and go back into Projects->Components, now pick your OCX control from the list. This will solve your problem.  If your OCX is not in the list than rebuild it independently first and try again.

This is an undocumented bug with the VB6 IDE. Even with VB6 SP6 it had not been solved.

Comment: thanks much!! finally I got around to test your suggestion, and it looks like it;s working! after un-checking/closing/saving/opening and checking back that component in the EXE project I got the OCX project stopping on the breakpoints. Who would have thought... :-)